# Attempted import error: 'Sonnet' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The React-Bootstrap code that I have used for ListGroups has a Component named "Sonnet" which perhaps has not been exported in the React-Bootstrap, due to which I am facing the 'Sonnet' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap' issue regardless of my attempts to even import it manually or import the complete React-bootstrap package with "*". I have not found a single thread or a blog which even lists "Sonnet" errors or anything for that matter. Need you guys to help me understand!

My attempts have been:
 reinstalling bootstrap/
 import {Sonnet} from 'react-bootstrap';/
 import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

None seem to work

The sample for ref:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
//import './Assets/css/default.min.css';
//import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Card,ListGroup,Tab,Row,Col,Sonnet} from 'react-bootstrap';
class Data extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <data>
            <div className="data">
            <Tab.Container id="list-group-tabs-example" defaultActiveKey="#link1">
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                    <ListGroup>
                        <ListGroup.Item> Online Devices
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item action href="#link1">
                        Soil Sensor
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item action href="#link2">
                        Level Sensor
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={8}>
                    <Tab.Content>
                        <Tab.Pane eventKey="#link1">
                            <Sonnet/>
                         Soil sensor
                        </Tab.Pane>
                        <Tab.Pane eventKey="#link2">
                        <Sonnet/>
                         Level Sensor
                        </Tab.Pane>
                    </Tab.Content>
                    </Col>

                </Row>

                </Tab.Container>
            </div>
        </data>
        );
}
}
export default Data;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand 'Sonnet' as just placeholder. Consider it as a dummy class. Instead of 'Sonnet', replace it with your own class. I will show you how I did.

This is original template from react-bootstrap document.

```
    <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
      <Sonnet />
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
      <Sonnet />
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" disabled>
      <Sonnet />
    </Tab>
```

If I apply this into my own project...

```
    <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
      <SignUp />
      {/* <Sonnet /> */}
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
      <SignIn />
      {/* <Sonnet /> */}
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" disabled>
      {/* <Sonnet /> */}
    </Tab>
  </Tabs>
```

'SignUp' and 'SignIn' is my own react component.

Answer (score 1):

You must replace `"<Sonnet />"` with your own class, that you want to render.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, replace `<Sonnet />` with your own class, that you want to render.

```js
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="home" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
  <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
    <TabContent />
    {/* <Sonnet /> */}
    </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
     <TabContent />
   {/* <Sonnet /> */}
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" disabled>
      <TabContent />
   {/* <Sonnet /> */}
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```